# Going back-and-forth between Belgium and Germany on a Schengen visa

Tags: schengen

I have a Schengen visa valid from October 1st to October 30th 2014.
First country of visit is Belgium and after I want to go for Germany.
It is possible to go back to Belgium after Germany?

Answer (score 7):

It's not a problem. As long as you don't exceed your visa's maximum stay or period of validity, you can stay in the Schengen area and crossing *internal* borders (borders between Schengen countries) does not make any difference. In all likelihood, you won't even see a border guard when traveling between Belgium and Germany.

Your visa will also have a specific number of allowed entries (1, 2 or ‘MULT’ for “multiple entries”, which means no limit) but that's only relevant when crossing *external* borders (borders between a Schengen country and some other country that is not part of the Schengen area).

Comment: Should you still be worried, this is the border crossing: https://www.google.com/maps/place/Germany/@50.2366535,6.1813265,3a,75.4y,336.44h,83.51t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1siFkVuMKL7v7iUMQR0WGKxg!2e0!4m2!3m1!1s0x479a721ec2b1be6b:0x75e85d6b8e91e55b

Comment: @AndreasBonini/Relaxed: I don't know what it's like now, but I took the train into Germany several times between 1999 and 2005, entering from NL, France, and Austria (maybe from Switzerland, too). There were generally several German border officers walking through the train between the last non-German station and the first German station. They typically interviewed certain people with varying degrees of intensity; the targets of this scrutiny were easily predicted by physical appearance. By contrast, the first train I took from DE to NL was swept by a single Dutch guard who spoke to nobody.

Comment: @phoog That's why I wrote “in all likelihood”. I have been on trains between NL and DE without seeing anyone but, like yourself, I did occasionally see German or Dutch border guards going through the train (although perhaps less frequently now than in the years immediately after the implementation of the Schengen agreement). I also witnessed cars from the customs (Zoll/Douane) watching the motorway (like parked on a service entrance, ready to chase someone…) Other borders (France/Italy) seem to be even more intensively patrolled and I have often heard about racial profiling there.

Comment: I can tell you that in august I did italy => switzerland => germany => belgium => netherlands => belgium => germany => france => italy, and never seen a single border guard. Except for switzerland of course, where there are still regular borders.

Comment: @AndreasBonini Not quite, Switzerland is part of the Schengen area (and hasn't performed systematic checks in quite some time, even before that) but you're right, it's quite common to see no checks at all.

Comment: @Relaxed: what I meant is that in switzerland there are "manned buildings" at borders, and you have to slow down and look at the border guard, who typically just nods and you go ahead. Between, for example, german and the netherlands, there is just a sign -- no building, and no guards (or at least, that's my experience)

Comment: @AndreasBonini No, not everywhere by a long shot. I know many roads with a sign and a building that's empty at most times. But it's true that on the main motorways there will often be guards and a chicane. Incidentally, outside of Western Europe, “regular borders” tends to mean at least a short stop and a look at the passport, nodding at passing cars is already pretty relaxed.